# Distance between a set and a point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

A set A $\subseteq$ $\mathbb C$ is given and for each $z \in \mathbb C$, define $dist(z,A):= inf_{a \in A } ||z-a||$.

I'm trying to prove for every z $\in A$, $dist(z,\mathbb C-A)= dist(z, \partial A)$

My attempt:
First, show $dist(z, \mathbb C - A) \le dist(z, \partial A)$ by
$dist(z,\mathbb C - A) = dist(z, cl (\mathbb C -  A))$ and $\partial A \subseteq cl(\mathbb C - A)$.

I'm stuck at this point. I tried to show that the negation of the inequality gives the contradiction but fails. So I tried to show the other direction of the inequality but also fails. I think my approach is not wrong but there are some point I couldn't figure out precisely.

Comment: Do you need the assumption that $z\in A$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the inequality $dist(z, \partial A) \leq d(z,\mathbb C-A)$ using a connectedness argument. Suppose $w\in \mathbb C-A$. Consider the line segment $[z,w]$. This is connected. Hence it must intersect $\partial A$. [ Otherwise the interior and the exterior of $A$ would give a disconnection of the line segment].
 So there exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that $tz+(1-t)w \in \partial A$. Now $dist(z, \partial A) \leq |z-(tz+(1-t)w )| =(1-t)|z-w| \leq |z-w|$. Finish the proof by taking infimum over all $w \in \mathbb C-A$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the given condition that $z \in A$

Comment: @J.Bo Edited my answer accordingly.